# How to get IntelliJ to associate Gradle sources with build.gradle?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When writing Gradle scripts for my Java project, specifically, when writing *build.gradle* files, IntelliJ does not recognize the Gradle API.

For instance, Gradle methods calls like `apply`, `dependencies` `configure` appear with a black line under them and it is not possible to navigate to method declarations, there is no auto-completion etc.

I managed to work around this by adding `compile gradleApi()` to the build's `dependencies` block. However, I don't want to have this explicit dependency in my code.

I tried editing IntelliJ's project structure and add a dependency on a Gradle library (tried *gradle-core* and *gradle-all*) to my modules, but that seems to have no effect.

Is there a way to make IntelliJ associate all *build.gradle* files with the Gadle sources?

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem as follows:

1. As mention in already posted answers, [configure gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html)

- update `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file
  change `bin` to `all` in distributionUrl i.e.
  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip`
  to
  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-all.zip`
  OR
  [optional] If you are using old version of gradle wrapper and wanted to upgrade, then execute

  ```bash
  ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.8.3 --distribution-type all
  ```
- Update [gradle task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) (if present in build file)

  ```
  wrapper {
      gradleVersion = '6.8.3'
      distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
  }
  ```

2. Before importing the project to IntelliJ-Idea IDE, update `build.gradle` and add `java` and `idea` plugin to the plugins list

   ```
   plugins {
       id "java-library"
       id "idea"
   }
   ```
3. From a terminal, execute `./gradlew clean build idea` or simply `./gradlew idea`
4. Import project to IntelliJ idea.
   Go to `Preferences` --> `build,Execution,Deployment` --> `BuildTools` --> `Gradle`
   You can see (old IntelliJ-idea) [image: options to choose]

   New intelliJ-idea [image: options to choose]
5. Restart IntelliJ idea IDE.

---

So above we have configured both of the options so choose either of them, except the specified location option. That's it.

### Before

[image: Before]

### After

[image: after]

Autocomplete functionality as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443267/2987755) answer.

[image: autocomplete]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar frustrations with Grails 3, which defines and runs a wrapper task when an app is created. Changing to the "all" zip in the wrapper properties file did not work because this kept getting changed back to the "bin" zip.

This was solved when it was understood that the "gradle-wrapper.properties" file simply stores the values from the "wrapper" task, and if this task is run after the properties are changed, they get changed right back.

This is easily fixed by setting some properties on the wrapper task:

```
wrapper.gradleVersion='3.2.1'
wrapper.distributionType=Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
```

Now importing the project into IDEA gives you smart editing of your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

when I choose `build.gradle` in IDEA and open it, IDE prompts

```
You can configure Gradle wrapper to use distribution with sources. It will provide IDE with Gradle API/DSL documentation.
```

I choose `Ok, apply suggestion!`

after project refreshing I am able to use code completion 
[image]

Comment: In your picture, it looks like for you it works.

However, I already did that. This changes a line inside `gradle-wrapper.properties` from `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-bin.zip` to `+distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip`.

But there's no effect in my projects. Still I have no auto completion, no method recognition and no possibility to navigate to source.

Comment: when you import gradle project, did you choose `use default gradle wrapper` ?

Comment: Yes, I did choose "use default gradle wrapper".

Answer (score 0):

before you import your project, configure it to use the customizable gradle wrapper as per the instructions here :-

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

add a task to your top level project like this:-

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    println "Wrapper gradleVersion = '2.12'"
    gradleVersion = '2.12'
}
```

or whatever the latest version is.

make sure you can build the project from the gradle command line before you try importing into intelliJ, using the ./gradlew command, which will download and install a gradle distribution for you the first time you build.

set your java home, intelliJ home and gradle home variables in your machine and in intelliJ (mine look like this, yours may be different depending on your setup and your history of hacking around your machine...:-

(from .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

)

[image: IntelliJPaths]

When you do import, choose the customisable gradle wrapper. if all is well, when you open the top level build.gradle for your project, you will be asked to configure sources for the gradle dsl, which will also update your gradle wrapper properties file to this:-

```
#Thu Mar 31 14:04:00 BST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip
```

.. the change being from ... bin.zip to all.zip. and that's it. This had been giving me lots of grief for a long time, but that's the way to do it. (on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 CE at least...)

most of this was in
[Dimitry's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3278460/dmitry-agibov) answer too, but I couldn't get it to work using the default wrapper , it had to be the customisable wrapper.