# IntelliJ complains about an inaccessible class that's accessible

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I reimported a project into IntelliJ but it complains that I have a compiler error in a build file because some class is not accessible:

[image]

The fact is that the build runs properly if I run `./gradlew clean build` from the CLI and there isn't really an error. What can I do to make IntelliJ understand that the function I'm calling is accessible?

I tried

- reimporting the project
- Invalidating the cache
- Deleting the `.gradle` and the `build` folders
- Reloading all Gradle projects

But the error persists.

IntelliJ details:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-212.5080.55, built on August 24, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.16 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 750M
Cores: 16
Registry: ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.4lex4.intellij.solarized (2.4.0), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.5.30-release-409-IJ4638.7)
Kotlin: 212-1.5.30-release-409-IJ4638.7
```

Comment: Please add which intellij-idea version with kotlin version.

Comment: I've added that too.

Comment: Some more checks you can give a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162761/2987755, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58490943/2987755